# C# MVC : MapRoute is adding /index to urls after I changed the default Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

as you know MVC default route is

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Public_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new {
                 controller = "Home",
                 action = "Index",
                 id = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        )
```

and calling **Url.Action("")** was returning **"/MyController"**

After I changed the default route to :

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Public_default",
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{slug}",
            new {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Index",
                id = UrlParameter.Optional,
                slug = UrlParameter.Optional
            }
        )
```

Now calling **Url.Action("")** is returning **"/MyController/Index"**

The problem is the **"/index"**. it seems it's ignoring **action = "Index"** in route defaults.

I think it's happening because of adding {slug} to route.

note: when I call **/MyController** it's working like before. but Url.Action("") behavior is changed.

How can I solve this problem ?

Comment: `Url.Action` (and other helpers) take the current context (RouteData) into equation when generating routes. I don't know from which page you're trying to generate a link from, but most likely it's taking those route values into equation.

Comment: @BradChristie I'm calling it from the same controller. for example inside "home" controller and "about" action

Answer (score 1):

surprisingly I put **both** Routes in route config and it solved the problem...
But I think it's a misbehavior for Url.Action()

Comment: The issue is that the route contained 2 optional parameters (only the last one should be optional) which means that the routing engine can not resolve it. If for example you changed the id parameter to `id=1`(not optional), then it would return just `"/MyController"`